# Black box around matplotlib graph in Tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm embedding a pyplot graph in a Tkinter frame. There's a thick black line around the entire figure that I'd like to get rid of. It only appears when my Tkinter window is actively selected:

[image: pyplot with black border]

I'm using Python 2.7.6 on Mac OS 10.9. Here's my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

class PlotFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.plot = self.fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(N), padx=20, pady=20)


root = Tk()
plot_frame = PlotFrame(root)
plot_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is controlled by the `highlightthickness` and `highlightcolor` attributes of the canvas widget. Set `highlightthickness` to zero if you don't want to see it.

Comment: This worked for me with one minor modification. Since my canvas was an instance of `FigureCanvasTkAgg`, I had to update `highlightthickness` via `self.canvas._tkcanvas.config(highlightthickness=0)` rather than `self.canvas.config(highlightthickness=0)`.